# Codeigniter invalid link opens as a valid link

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried building a news section page on my codeigniter project.
i have my class 'admin' and a function 'articles', normally the valid url is **localhost/admin/articles**
but when i visit **localhost/admin/articles/anything** it still opens the articles page.

Below is the code for articles

```
<?php
class Admin extends CI_Controller {
      public function articles() {
        $data['volume'] = $this->user_model->get_volume();
        $data['issue'] = $this->user_model->get_issue();
        $data['article'] = $this->user_model->get_articles();
        $data['title'] = "Admin Panel - Articles";
        $this->parser->parse('admin/head',$data);
        $this->parser->parse('admin/articles',$data);
      }
}
```

my route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

.htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The normal url is **localhost/admin/articles**, but adding anything after articles, e.g **localhost/admin/articles/hello/world** , still opens the articles page.

Comment: I don't know, I cannot see what you have done. What's in your routes and what's in admin/articles method?

Comment: You need to understand how the URI rewriting works in codeigniter. In your case `admin` is the controller name, `articles` is the method name and anything after that are parameters. If you are not doing anything with those parameters, they get ignored and thus you are served always the same content. Without seeing your controller code, however, it's very difficult to provide any further insight